# Large gap between garage door and floor - seal into slot?

Tags: garage, garage-door

There's a large-ish gap between the bottom of our garage door and the concrete floor where rodents are getting in. Since the gap is larger than standard seals, an exterminator mentioned a product he saw that was a seal that inserts into some sort of long slot... but he didn't know who made it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post a phot and the measurement of the gap.  In theory you can get anything made of rubber and glue it to the bottom if the door.

Comment: Rodents will need something hard like cement or metal to stop them, if the gap cannot be reduced.  Rodents can chew though any soft stuff like wood/plastic/rubber/foam.

Answer (score 2):

If the gap is uniform along the whole length of the door, you may be able to adjust the limit screws to lower the end height.
Check if your door has them. They may be located under the light bulb protection.

[image: garage door opener- limit screws]